# return empty list when using a for loop with if statement for a 2 variables i,j python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, conditional-statements, python-itertools

I want to add some elements to a list that satisfy a condition, so I used a generator to make a for loop to do it. The problem arises when I use the same generator to make a second list. The problem is that the first one gets the elements I desire, the second one returns empty. Here is the code:

```
import itertools
n = 4
xxvars = [["x."+str(i+1)+"."+str(j+1) for j in range(n)]for i in range(n)]
yyvars = [["y."+str(i+1)+"."+str(j+1) for j in range(n)]for i in range(n)]

gen = ((i,j) for i,j in itertools.product(range(n),range(1,n)) if i != j)

thevars1 = [xxvars[i][j] for (i,j) in gen]
thevars2 = [yyvars[i][j]for (i,j) in gen]
```

This returns:

```
thevars1 = ['x.1.2','x.1.3','x.1.4','x.2.3','x.2.4','x.3.2','x.3.4','x.4.2','x.4.3']
thevars2 = []
```

The desired output should be:

```
thevars1 = ['x.1.2','x.1.3','x.1.4','x.2.3','x.2.4','x.3.2','x.3.4','x.4.2','x.4.3']
thevars2 = ['y.1.2','y.1.3','y.1.4','y.2.3','y.2.4','y.3.2','y.3.4','y.4.2','y.4.3']
```

Is there something wrong with my code, or am i missing something else?

Comment: are your shift keys broken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the generator expression has been iterated over once, it cannot be iterated over again.

You can verify this by running `next(gen)`, which raises a `StopIteration` exception.

```
>>> next(gen)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-41-8a6233884a6c>", line 1, in <module>
    next(gen)
StopIteration
```

To use a generator multiple times, you can return it from a function

```
def create_generator():
    return ((i, j) for i, j in itertools.product(range(n), range(1,n)) if i != j)
```

or use the generator syntax

```
def create_generator():
    for i,j in itertools.product(range(n),range(1,n)):
        if i != j:
            yield i, j
```

Then you can call it as

```
thevars1=[xxvars[i][j] for (i,j) in create_generator()]
thevars2=[yyvars[i][j]for (i,j) in create_generator()]
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the `gen` is a generator object. Once a generator object is consumed, it can't be reused. You must recall it to generate a generator object again.

Answer (score 1):

Both of the other answers are correct.  Here is one way to accomplish what you want:

```
import itertools
n=4
xxvars=[["x."+str(i+1)+"."+str(j+1) for j in range(n)]for i in range(n)]
yyvars=[["y."+str(i+1)+"."+str(j+1) for j in range(n)]for i in range(n)]

def f():
    return ((i,j) for i,j in itertools.product(range(n),range(1,n)) if i!=j)
thevars1=[xxvars[i][j] for (i,j) in f()]
thevars2=[yyvars[i][j] for (i,j) in f()]
```

Comment: It's nice that you give the answer in code, but you really should explain to the OP why their code isn't working. It's not worth posting a new answer just to say "the other answers are correct", especially when @Andrew already has excellent code in his answer

Comment: You're right but when I posted this there was no code in his answer.  I didn't provide an explanation because the others had already done so.